# Angular 4.0.3 - Unable to find css

Tags: css, angular

**Versions**

```
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.3",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.2.0"
"@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
```

I updated the package.json today. The dependencies above were part of that update. 
When I run the application (npm start), the app is unable to find css files on the server. I haven't changed any reference or location.

**Index.html**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

The app is able to find the favicon, but not the css. Both files are in the same /src folder.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I use the CLI. Added under versions

Comment: Check for file `angular-cli.json`, find `"styles"` and check if there is `styles.css` file (styles is default name, in your case it should be `test.css`).

Comment: And if you have multiple styles, you can add multiple css files there

Comment: Oke, found the styles array. Added test.css. GET test.css and GET styles.css fail. I first used materialize.css. After the package update the css could be found anymore.

Comment: Thath's weird, are you sure that your css file is in the same folder as `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, directly under /src, same level as the default favicon and styles.css.

Comment: One more try: please go to `angular-cli.json` file again and find `"defaults"`, check if `"styleExt"` is set to `"css"`.

Comment: Yes, it that setting is correct. Using the old package.json also not working. What could break the css? The app is working fine.

Comment: It's not meant to be included in a tag in `index.html`. The cli uses webpack, which "bundles" all referenced css as "javascript" and "injects" the styles. So just reference within the styles array and remove the `link` from `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution for me. Thanks all for helping. Is this changed in a update or was this always the way to go?

Comment: @Haseoh It's now `.angular-cli.json`, with a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not using the index.html for including css/js. Use .angular-cli.json instead.